# ASP.Net Final Rendering Page Event

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

Perhaps my previous question on [output caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362980/asp-net-invalid-page-caching) output caching was too complex.

Let's simplify.

How can I get the final, "ready for sending" rendered HTML from a page (or control) event in ASP.Net?  I assume that this will be the same content that will be used for the output cache, so could be queried to find out what is about to be placed into the cache.

Comment: Would like to understand what is the objective ?

Comment: Hi Madhur, I am trying to 'examine' what will be going into the output cache BEFORE it goes in, as once in a great while the site caches an invalid partial page.  I would like to cache this before it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code copied from:
http://aspcode.net/Last-second-HTML-changes-in-your-ASPNET-page.aspx

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
{ 
    using(System.IO.MemoryStream msOur = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) 
    { 
        using(System.IO.StreamWriter swOur = new System.IO.StreamWriter(msOur)) 
        { 
            HtmlTextWriter ourWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swOur); 
            base.Render(ourWriter); 
            ourWriter.Flush(); 
            msOur.Position = 0; 
            using(System.IO.StreamReader oReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(msOur)) 
            { 
                string sTxt = oReader.ReadToEnd();                     
                Response.Write(sTxt); 
                oReader.Close(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will only catch things that are rendered normally, and not Server.Execute or other statements that write directly to the Response.Out stream.

Comment: Thanks Madhur.  I'm not sure if the output cache directly uses the output from .Render, but it looks like a promising avenue to explore.  +1 and accepted.